# TOP 2 of paired columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 PortPair   caspid  por POD teu ton
  P1-P2        5    P1  P2  9   5000
 P3-P4         5    P3  P4  10  5500
 P1-P2         4    P1  P2  7   4000
 P1-P2         3    P1  P2  5   3000
 P3-P4         3    P3  P4  6   3500
 P3-P4         2    P3  P4  7   4500
 P1-P2         1    P1  P2  3   2500
```

here i have a table, i want to get the out put of each PortPair top 2 records only.
out put is like like below

```
 Por    pod PortPair caspID  teu     ton
  P1    P2  P1-P2     5        9    5000
  P1    P2  P1-P2     4        7    4000
  P3    P4  P3-P4     5       10    5500
  P3    P4  P3-P4     3        6    3500
```

Not getting idea of how to query for my output table..

Can any one please help

Comment: How would you like to handle ties? If #2 and #3 both have 4000 tons, which should show? Both? Random?

Comment: In the future, consider not tagging SQL Server versions you don't need support for.

Comment: thank you for your advice Joachim Isaksson.. i am the new person to stack over flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PortPair ORDER BY CASPID DESC ) AS rno,
       Por  ,  
       pod, 
       PortPair, 
       caspID , 
       teu   ,  
       ton
   FROM tableName
}

SELECT Por  ,  pod, PortPair, caspID , teu   ,  ton
FROM cte 
WHERE rno<=2
```

Here we are `partitioning` based on your `pair` and `ordering` based on proper column in descending order. So that we can select top 2 pairs.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server 2000 can do `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: it is tagged to sql server 2008 and r2 also

Comment: i got the solution when i modify your query like.... 
   SELECT
  Por,
         pod,
         PortPair,
         caspID ,
         teu,
         ton
FROM
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PortPair ORDER BY CASPID DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
         Por,
         pod,
         PortPair,
         caspID ,
         teu,
         ton        
      FROM #tempcasp
      )T
WHERE RowNumber <= 2

Comment: ok. Am not well understood about the partition and pairing. Thats y. anyway i will update mu answer.